# how to plot multiple graphs in one plot?

Tags: programming, plotting, graph

I want a plotting script that will plot multiple graphs on the same plot where the values of my data have the same `x` coordinate. This will show the differences of each variable in the plot. I tried to plot using spreadsheet, but the plots are not clearly identifiable each other. My data looks like:

```
x y1 y2 y3 y4 

1 10 25 28 30 
2 20 15 40 20 
3 10 10 30 20 
4 2 5 15 30    
. . . .
```

Comment: Have a look at [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/), it has a great manual.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have all the data in a file named `data.txt`, the a typical GnuPlot script would contain:

```
# Set the output file type
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color solid colortext 9
# Set the output file name
set output 'multiple_plots.eps'

# Now plot the data with lines and points
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 w lp title 'y1', \
     '' using 1:3 w lp title 'y2', \
     '' using 1:4 w lp title 'y3', \
     '' using 1:4 w lp title 'y4'
```

You can save the above code in a file say, `plot.gp`, and execute it with GnuPlot as:

```
gnuplot plot.gp
```

Please refer to the [GnuPlot website](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for further details and a lot of demo scripts.

Comment: your script works great. I want the lines to be smooth with colors only in the legend and in the plot. Now it has box, stars with the color. Can you let me know how to remove those things?

Comment: So, you want only the lines? In the above code replace `w lp` with `w l`. This indicates that the plots should be done only with lines; `w` is the abbreviation for "with", and `l` is the abbreviation for "lines".

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now the plots look as I wanted for presentation. Awesome!!

Comment: @Abraham Glad to hear that! Also, please look at the site mentioned in the answer for many other different plot types and features.

Comment: `'' using 1:4 w lp title 'y3', \
     '' using 1:4 w lp title 'y4'` you plotted 1:4 twice, maybe a minor typo